# Wrong fitting of data to curve using curve_fit from scipy

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to to fit my data to a curve using the function `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`. Given certain values, the function works the way I want it to. As such:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit    

def f1(x, a, b):
    return a*((1-(x/b))**2)

x_given = [450, 500, 525, 575, 625]
y_given = [33.8, 32.5, 32, 30.2, 28.4]

params, extras = curve_fit(f1, x_given, y_given)

x_new = list(range(-1000, 10000, 1))

plt.plot(x_given, y_given, 'o', markersize=10, color='r')
plt.plot(x_new, f1(x_new, params[0], params[1]))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

And gives the following curve:

[image: figure 1]
However when I try to fit different data by changing `x_given` and `y_given` to `x_given = [875, 850, 825, 800]` and `y_given = [26, 26.75, 27.25, 28]`, the following error shows up:

```
RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has    
reached maxfev = 600.
```

So I increased `maxfev` till the error stops showing up:

```
def f1(x, a, b):
    return a*((1-(x/b))**2)

x_given = [875, 850, 825, 800]
y_given = [26, 26.75, 27.25, 28]

params, extras = curve_fit(f1, x_given, y_given, maxfev=3700)
x_new = list(range(-1000, 10000, 1))
```

However, now I get a wrong fitting of the curve. The left part of the curve should be where the points are.

[image]

I'm not sure how to correct this. Or if adjusting `maxfev` is the right way to do it?

Comment: Basically you got a reasonable approximation. To get a better one start with a closer initial guess `params, extras = curve_fit(f1, x_given, y_given, p0=[2000**2, 2000])`.

Comment: @Aguy Oh. I see what you mean. That worked out well! Thank you!